# compiling fileZilla on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to compiler FileZilla from its source code. 
It requires C++ 14 support for which gcc4.9 is required. 
Whatever higher version than 4.8, I try to install, there's no change.

Is gcc4.9 not available for the above ubuntu version?

The error I get is:

```
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features with -std=gnu++14... no
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features with -std=gnu++1y... no
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features with -std=c++14... no
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features with -std=c++1y... no
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++14 language features is required
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: check the following link http://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9 may be helpful, and set it as your default gcc.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9
```

Then gcc-4.9 will be available in your ubuntu version.

Notes : my version is ubuntu 14.04